# Why does SwiftKey lose "full access" on a phone reboot?

Tags: ios, swiftkey

I'm using [SwiftKey](http://swiftkey.com/en/) on my iPhone 5s (iOS 8), and have it set as the default keyboard, with Emoji also enabled. I have removed the default keyboard.

Whenever I reboot my iPhone, SwiftKey seems to lose it's "full access" rights; at least, each keyboard I bring up warns about this, and the keyboard is using the default theme, rather than the one I selected. If I got into the Settings app, and change the SwiftKey full access permissions to off, and then on again, it starts working again.

This is irritating. Is this by design, or is this a bug?

Comment: What's your iOS 8 ver?

Comment: I'm on iOS 8.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that 8.0.2's update for iOS fixed the problem for me.